# How to migrate plugin from ga.js to gtag.js

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

Please see the plugin guide for google analytics https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/writing-plugins

We have a plugin running on ga.js now and are trying to migrate it to gtag.js.  But, I cannot find any plugin info for gtag.js: https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/reference/api

Can anyone give me some hints or directions?  Thanks!

To be more specific, the plugin may look like this:

```
function MyPlugin() {
   $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "someurl rather than GA",
      data: { name: ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId')}
   });
}
```

Comment: can you add more info about what your plugin do? Have you checked https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/ ?

Comment: @Eduardo updated my post

Comment: @Eduardo gtag.js doesn't seem to support plugins yet. Docs have no mention of plugins.